# Why does this not work: link_to(current_user) do

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= link_to(current_user) do %>
  #show other stuff between anchors like this:
  #<a href="/user/bob">show other stuff between anchors</a>
<% end %>
```

The error I get is:

```
compile error
syntax error, unexpected ')'
...t(( link_to(current_user) do ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat ...
```

Why an `unexpected ')'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the "=" at the beginning of the link_to tag implies "take what's in this tag and output it as a string" (hence the "to_s" in the error message).

Comment: This is right, you just need to take out the = and it will work as expected.